# how to free the camera

Tags: opencv, camera

How can I release the camera when application keeps on running. It is still in on condition. here is the code. I don't know how to release it

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>

main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
    int i=1;
    CvCapture* capture = NULL;
    capture = cvCreateCameraCapture( 0 );
    IplImage *frames = cvQueryFrame(capture);


    while(1) {
        if (i==20)
        cvReleaseCapture ( &capture );

        char c = cvWaitKey(33);
        if( c == 27 ) break;
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn't totally clear so I hope I'm understanding correctly, but I think what you want is something more like this...

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) 
{
    int i=1;
    CvCapture* capture = NULL;
    capture = cvCreateCameraCapture( 0 );
    IplImage *frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);

    while(1) 
    {
        // if we are on the 20th frame, quit.
        if (i==20)
        {
            cvReleaseCapture ( &capture );
            break;
        }

        // if the user types whatever key 27 corresponds to, quit.
        char c = cvWaitKey(33);
        if( c == 27 )
        {
            cvReleaseCapture ( &capture );
            break;
        }
        // do you want to get the next frame?  here.
        frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Your problem is that you are not breaking after releasing the capture, so you will continue in the loop with a released camera.  Also, you had `IplImage *frames` instead of `IplImage *frame`.  That will only point to a single frame at a time, so I figured renaming it would be helpful for you.

Comment: Chris I didn't break it purposely. I want to release the camera while the process is alive. In this case the process will close when it reaches 20th frame.

Comment: @user2551056 The process can still live if you do something afterwards.  Can you give me a use case?  I'm having a hard time understanding your problem.  You have to keep calling `cvQueryFrame' to get new frames from the camera, but if you release the camera you can't do that (your program will crash).

Comment: I am sorry for not giving the complete information. I want to use the camera in another process without killing the first one. For example if I run the second process which uses camera gives the following error VIDIOC_STREAMON: Inappropriate ioctl for device. first process is not releasing the camera and I want it to be alive.

Comment: There's nothing in your code to share the camera between processes (and I wouldn't recommend that at all).  If you want a different process to use the camera, you should put the calling code in that process.  How are you calling the camera from the second process?